# Add class if parent element contains class

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class when clicking on an element. However, if the parent of this class already has this class in it, it should remove this class first. It does not seem to work. All it does is add new classes, but it doesn't remove the existing ones.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var par = $(this).parent('div').attr("class");
    if(par.has(".active")){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

My HTML structure would be

```
<div class="container">
   <a class="btn">button</a>
   <a class="btn">button</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <a class="btn">button</a>
   <a class="btn">button</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <a class="btn">button</a>
   <a class="btn">button</a>
</div>
```

Every container can contain only 1 active class, so three in total in this case.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all. You've bound your click event to `.option`, but there is no element with that class!

Comment: There are several problems with your code:  (1) you've bound your event to a class that doesn't exist in your markup; (2) `.has()` will search for contained elements, not the targeted element's class; (3) you're removing class "active" only to add it again right away, which of course will happen but so fast you wouldn't notice it; (4) you're checking if a string (`par` has a class name) contains an element, but strings can't contain elements.

Comment: @DerekHenderson `which of course will happen but so fast you wouldn't notice it;` - it has nothing to do with something happening fast enough. It's because the calls are in the same execution context, and the DOM won't be repainted until its end. By that time, the element has the class again, so nothing ended up changing. You could loop for 5 seconds, removing and adding the class, and you'll never see a change.

Comment: @DerekHenderson That was a typo of mine here on StackOverflow. it should be .btn in this case.

Comment: @MitchelJager, it's also not clear where you want to remove/add classes.  Do you want to remove an "active" class from `div.container` and added it to the `a` tag, or remove it from the other `a` tag in `div.container` and add it to the one clicked?

Comment: Just for future reference [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.btn').on('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        var parent = $(self).parent();

        parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(self).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/aluyom/1/edit.

EDIT:

There is no need to use an `if` statement. This line `parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');` will remove the class if found.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's due to either using .attr() and/or .has() with a dot in the class name, try with this :

```
if($(this).parent('div').hasClass("active"))
```